# Should the main WPF window directly launch a new page?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I want to create a multi-page WPF application, but the buttons on the initial window stuck around when navigating to any new pages.

To get around this, I have the main window immediately go to a new "main page".  This seems to solve the issue.

Is this the expected way of dealing with this issue, or is there a better way of managing this?

Edit: The way I was navigating between pages was as follows, and only caused any unwanted effects when navigating away from the main page.

```
private void BackBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
    }
```

Or like so

```
private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainFrame.Content = new Page2();
    }
```

Comment: I would even say it is a better way. To leave the shell as that, a shell.

Comment: If buttons are still visible, one is not `navigating` to a new page. Can you show how that navigation occurs?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I've updated the post to show the ways I was navigating between pages. It seems to work fine, unless the buttons are placed within the main window directly.

Comment: Its hard to comprehend, my suggestion is to create a test project which demonstrates the issue in its most basic form. Then you can either learn what is going wrong (a difference between a working and non working) or be able to provide a gist example for us to try out on our own boxes. ????